# Calling KernelScan in AleaGPU C#

Tags: c#, .net, gpu, aleagpu

I am trying to use the AllInOne<> function given by Alea Gpu in the Alea.LibParallel.KernelScan library.
However I keep running into this error:

> System.Exception: 'Length of shared array must be kernel compile-time constant.

This is the code I'm using to call the function:

```
int[] scanInput = new int[100];
for(int i = 0; i <100; i++)
{
    scanInput[i] = 100;
}
int[] scanOut = new int[100];

var scanInGPU = gpu.AllocateDevice(scanInput);
var scanOutGPU = gpu.AllocateDevice(scanOut);

var scanOutPtr = scanOutGPU.Ptr;
var scanInPtr = scanInGPU.Ptr;

Func<int, int, int> op = new Func<int, int, int>((a, b) => { return a + b; });

LaunchParam lp = new LaunchParam(griddim, blockdim);
sesh.Launch(KernelScan.AllInOne, lp, 2, 50, op, 0, scanOutPtr, scanInPtr, 0, 100);
```

Is there a way to get this function working so I can call it from within another Kernel that is running on the GPU? Or will I have to write my own scan kernel?

I can't use the GPUExtension.Scan() function because that won't be possible to call from within an already running kernel, however it should be possible with this function.